# Google drive links. What version they shows?

Tags: google-drive

Does links from drive give a connection to the last version of a file or to the one at the moment of link creation?

Answer (score 1):

Link always points to the file you  linked at that point of time

If you want to update the link to point to revise version of the file so that others with whom you shared view the latest version, open the [web version of Google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive) either using a PC or from Android using  browser desktop view, select the file and upload as shown below

- Select the file (highlighted in blue), tap the 3 dot button (greyed out in pic below) and choose *manage versions*

[image]

- Upload the latest file (*Upload New Version*)

[image]