# Can I add a shortcut to a Google Drive file by name?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-drive

I have a file on my Google Drive that I want quick access to from my home screen.

The app that updates the file seems to do so by renaming the original file and then creating a new file with the original name.

This breaks my shortcut every time.

Can I set up a home screen shortcut so it links to the file by name, instead of whatever ID it's using?

(ETA a little background: The file in question is a KeePass database. I manage it on my phone with KeePassDroid, and on my desktop (Mac) with KeePassXC. My Mac syncs it to my Google Drive with Google Drive for Desktop. So I'm not in control of how the file gets saved, nor do I want to take the manual step of uploading it.)

Comment: Related [Google drive links. What version they shows?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/194172/131553)

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams – I don't think this is a versioned file, strictly speaking, but that might help someone else